# Global declaration over using viewWithTag: and declaring in viewDidLoad:

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, uiviewcontroller, declaration

I started a new project and I was wondering if anyone has experimented which is more efficient, declaring an object (a UIButton for example) in the .h file or to create the object in the viewDidLoad method and using the viewWithTag: method to access the element after it has been created.

Of course declaring it in the .h file would be the easiest but since my application will be heavy media-wise (lots of images) I was wondering if using tags would be better. By better I mean, that the application would use less memory, run smoother or such things of the like.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I look back on this question it seems like a silly question. The two should be the same memory usage since they both will allocate the same amount of memory. That being said having the reference to the object stored in the .h file should be better. It should be better since the viewWithTag function will do some processing to get the pointer to the object while the other way it will already be there in your class.

Answer (score 0):

I would use IBOutlet to access your UIViews declared in the XIB. What i would recommend is:

1) If there is alot of things going on, but you know how many they are (UILabels, UIButtons, UIViews, UIScrollViews, etc) I would create them in the XIB and then IBOulets so I could control them in the code. And it makes life easier for you (on a memory management perspective).

2) If you are not sure how many Views you will need, I would create them dynamically. Because it gives you freedom to add how many do you want.

My rule is: If I know how many views I will have, probably will create them in the XIB, if not dynamically.

Comment: I don't use Interface Builder. I rather do it all in code, it gives me more flexibility. I'm also familiar with the standard memory management of alloc/retain/release of an object. My question is more of a theoretical question.

Comment: I really can't be of much help then. I will give you a +1 for the question, because now I am curious. :)